# Is there a simple way to do hexadecimal arithmetic using sql server/TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, hex

I have a column of hexadecimal values in a table. I want to add a hex value to all values in that table. If it were a simple int I would run something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET num = num + 4000
```

Is there any way to do this simply using hexadecimal arithmetic? Or do I have to convert the column value to decimal, convert the value I want to add to decimal, add them, and convert the value back to hex? (And if so, what's the simplest way to do that?)

(NOTE: We are currently using sql server 2000.)

Comment: Why are you storing values that are obviously meant to be numeric as *strings*? If they should be displayed/entered as hex for users, that ought to be done by formatting code well away from the database.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I think it was to stop the numbers from getting incredibly large. Either way, that's the way it is now and I have to work with it...

Answer (score 4):

use something like :

```
print convert(varbinary(4),0 + 0x002E + 0x001D)
```

it should give you a result like :

```
0x0000004B
```

the zero in the equation fools it to believe its all numbers so it calculates the value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `num` is actually a string representation of the hexadecimal number, I think you can convert it to an integer by using a couple of User Defined Functions:

```
-- Based on Feodor's solution on
-- http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/01/sql-server-question-how-to-convert-hex-to-decimal/
CREATE FUNCTION fn_HexToInt(@str varchar(16))
RETURNS BIGINT AS BEGIN

SELECT @str=upper(@str)
DECLARE @i int, @len int, @char char(1), @output bigint
SELECT @len=len(@str),@i=@len, @output=case  WHEN @len>0 THEN 0 END

WHILE (@i>0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @char=substring(@str,@i,1)
         , @output=@output
                    +(ASCII(@char)
                        -(case when @char between 'A' and 'F' then 55
                          else case when @char between '0' and '9' then 48 end
                          end))
                                *power(16.,@len-@i)
        ,  @i=@i-1
END
RETURN @output
END

-- Example conversion back to hex string - not very tested
CREATE FUNCTION fn_IntToHex(@num int)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(16) AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @output varchar(16), @rem int
    SELECT @output = '', @rem=0
    WHILE (@num > 0)
    BEGIN   
        SELECT @rem = @num % 16
        SELECT @num = @num / 16
        SELECT @output = char(@rem + case when @rem between 0 and 9 then 48 else 55 end) + @output 
    END
    RETURN @output
END

select dbo.fn_HexToInt ('7FFF') -- = 32767
select dbo.fn_IntToHex(32767) -- = 7FFF
```

So you can try

```
UPDATE myTable
SET num = dbo.fn_IntToHex(dbo.fn_HexToInt(num) + 4000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prefix `0x` 
eg

```
Select 0x3F + 2
```

returns 65

So

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET num = num + 0x4000
```

(This works in SQL 2008 - I'm not sure if it's new since SQL 2000 - let me know!)

If you have two 0x values, they get concatenated by the `+` operator, so use convert to convert one of them to an int

Comment: this gives me the error - `Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals add, type equals varchar.`

Comment: No, then I get the error: `Syntax error converting the varchar value '7FFF' to a column of data type int.` I think the error is with `num`, not the 0x4000

Comment: So num isn't an int?? I think you may have to go the long way then